# Text in UITableCell runs outside of cell bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to display a table of questions and I can't seem to get each question to begin and end within the bounds of my `UITableViewCell`.

I have tried setting the alignment to the `center`and giving the `textLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap` but it doesn't seem to fix my current problem.

Here is a screenshot of what I mean:
[image]
[image]

Here is how I am setting up my `UITableView`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"MyCustomCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    }

    Questions *que = [survey.questions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"Que Value: %@\n", que);
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = (NSString *)que;

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 100.0;
}
```

Comment: Please give code of your `CustomCell` where you set `textLabel`

Comment: check that your frame or show your frame cell.textLabel

Comment: where is screenshot ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I added a screenshot where I log the cell.textLabel. Is that how I show the frame?

Comment: @AlokRao It's above in my question, do you not see it?

Comment: just print the log on cellforrowatindex

Comment: @AncAinu I added the code for my CustomCell above, i don't know what else you mean. I only have a CustomCell because I was previously trying to add buttons underneath each question but couldn't figure out how to do that. So I could go back to using the UITableViewCell. I have no real purpose for a CustomCell at the moment.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik sorry I'm fairly new still. How do I log that?

Answer (score 0):

you have not given label frame correctly. 
label must have leading and trailing constrains or fixed width.

Comment: I never added a label onto my cell in the story board. Is there a way to set those programmatically?

Comment: if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] ;

UILabel*UserName=[[UILabel alloc]init];
        UserName.frame=CGRectMake(80, 8, 150, 20);
        UserName.tag=3;
        UserName.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        UserName.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Semibold" size:13];
        //  UserDetail.text=@"Test";
        UserName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:UserName];
}

Comment: you can set the frame of label according to your requirement.

Comment: @voijtech vrbka i have given him an example how to set the frame of label. i don't think there is any problem with this example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly constrain your labels within the cell. Override the designated initializer of `UITableViewCell` (`init(style:reuseIdentifier:)`), and add constraints that:

- Pins the label's leading edge to the superview
- Pins the label's trailing edge to the superview

Alternatively, do this in your custom UITableViewCell subclass's nib file.

This will make the label fit within the bounds of the cell, left-right only. Do the same top-bottom if you want the cell to also fit vertically. You could even dynamically size the cell based on the text of the label this way.

Also, you don't need to do `if (cell == nil) {` anymore, as `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` is guaranteed to return a non-nil cell.

Comment: Is that it's on function or can i do that inside the cellForAtRowIndexPath?

Comment: I don't mean to ask you to walk me through this but I have no clue on how to code what you're saying. I'm only familiar with adding constraints in the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because of table view constraint. Set table view constraint properly i.e. leading/trailing top/bottom with respect to superview. This will solve your problem. All constraint's constant value should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide the `CustomCell` code, I'll assume you doing it by code.

Just override the method `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`, something like that:

```
    - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        [self loadView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

and the `loadView` method you should instantiate your `textLabel` do whatever configuration you want and create trailing and leading constraints, the method should looks like

```
- (void)loadView
{
// Do whatever configuration of textLabel
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.textLabel);
    [self.textLabel addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[self.textLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
}
```

I recommend you read about AutoLayout

**_ EDIT _**

If you aren't using a subclass, or a `CustomCell`, you can put at you `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` the same code, just updated for `cell.textLabel`, so something like that:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
// Do whatever configuration of textLabel
    NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell.textLabel);
    [cell.textLabel addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[self.textLabel]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I added this code but I am getting two errors. The first one says "No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the sector 'initiWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:'

Comment: I'm also getting 'No known class method for selector 'constraintWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views'

Comment: I got another error saying self.textLabel didn't exist in my current VC. I thought a textLabel automatically came with a default style cell. cell.textLabel doesn't work either so I created a property variable named textLabel

Comment: I never had any CustomCell code, so guessing that was my first mistake

Comment: A `CustomCell` need to be a subclass of `UITableViewCell`